# Office add-in is not shown in the menu

Tags: c#, vsto, ms-office, add-in

I have a problem connected with Office 2007 and VSTO add-in.

### Description:

Windows XP SP3 x86 
MS Office 2007 x86 (Enterprise edition)
VSTO add-in (Word, Excel)

**My VSTO add-in is not shown in the menu.**

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\MyAddin
LoadBehavior = 3

In Add-Ins tab (File->Options) I can see that my add-in is active. There are no any exceptions.

I can reproduce this issue in the following order:
1. install MS Office;
2. install add-in
    - .net framework 2.0 is installed;
    - add-in is installed.

But if .net framework had already been installed before I installed the Office -- add-in works in the right way.

1. install .net framework 2.0;
2. install MS Office
3. install add-in
   ----> add-in works properly...

On Windows 7 x86 (Office 2010 x86) add-in works. Maybe because Windows 7 already contains .net framework.

I can't resolve this issue... Maybe you can help me.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found cause of this issue. I have installed Primary Interop Assemblies for Office 2007 on end user system and my add-in works now.

1) [Issue explanation:](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2008/05/20/common-pitfalls-during-pia-deployment-and-installation.aspx)

*"The computer must have a version of the .NET Framework installed (version 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, or 3.5) before the PIA installer is run. Windows XP does not include any version of the .NET Framework unless .NET 1.1 was downloaded from Windows Update. Windows Vista does include a version of the .NET Framework. When Microsoft Office is first installed, the .NET Framework installation is detected and the PIAs are automatically installed."*

2) [Adding the Office PIAs as a prerequisite](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2008/05/08/adding-the-office-primary-interop-assemblies-as-a-prerequisite-in-your-clickonce-installer-mary-lee.aspx)

Maybe it will be useful for somebody.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you are missing the VSTO runtime files. If so then you can download those [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22327)

In order to see what the problem is you need to set an environment variable VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS=0 See [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms269003%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on MSDN and then specifically the last paragraph "Troubleshooting Add-ins Using a Log File and Error Messages"

Comment: I think It won't help me... because of existing situation: in different installation order add-in works properly. Maybe some dll's (or other files) in the Office more "right" for my add-in, and if I install Office after .net framework It will replace "wrong" files from .net framework... maybe it's nonsense, but I don't have any other ideas.
Thank you for your answer!

Comment: If you set the environment variables you are likely to get at least some information as to what is failing which might lead you to a solution or workaround.